# Wordpress 403 Error uploading media files

Tags: wordpress, http

I have a 403 error when I am trying to upload media files in my Wordpress.

```
403 (Forbidden) async-upload.
```

It saying `HTTP error` and when I'm looking in the console it's the `403 error`.

Answer (score -1):

Increase your `max_upload_size = 500M`

```
post_max_size = 500M
```

in `php.ini` file

Comment: I have the same error in the same file, even with uploads that are only a few kilobytes.   This solution would not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Delete** `.htaccess` files from all folders.